# Ionic app login screen appears even-though the user is logged-in

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I have a problem in my ionic app.

It is that, the login screen pops up for a few seconds before the app redirects to home page(probably till it authenticates with firebase). The login page is confusing for the user if it's logged in already.

In the routing (**app-routing.module.ts**), I have this :

```js
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }`
```

**Here is my code (in app.component.js):**

```js
    this.common.showLoader('Loading');  //show the loader(it shows up 
                                        //for a few seconds and disapperas)

    this.afAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(authData => {
      if (authData) {
        this.commonService.hideLoader(); //tried this. but not working
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      } else {
        this.commonService.hideLoader();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    });
```

I have tried using loader. But that does not seem to serve the purpose.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try storing a session token on the device that way you can have the user taken right to the `/home` route and do the auth check on that screen instead. You'll have network latency if you're trying to check with firebase before you authenticate the user.

Comment: @haron68 network latency is tolerable. The problem is with the login screen popping up unnecessarily :-p

Comment: Are you using angular authGuard?

Comment: no @haron68 no auth guard

Comment: @PrashanthBenny did you manage to find/implement a solution for the above? I am facing a similar issue although I am using Angular and MSAL for SSO.

Comment: I believe yes @pix1289 the answer and the comments helped me get there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will not be able to immediately tell if the user is authenticated, at the time a page is first loaded.  It takes some time for the Firebase Auth SDK to refresh and validate their auth token.

What you should do instead is show a loading/wait screen until you get the first `authState` callback.  That first callback indicates when the SDK is certain that the user is either definitely signed out or definitely signed in with a valid token.  That's information you can use to determine what to show next.

Comment: I am using firebase authhentication state. Have updated the question showing the routing-module as well. would you please look a it...

Comment: The reason you're seeing the login page flash before signing in is because you're telling the app to redirectTo login as soon as the root route is hit. You need to make your loading screen appear first as this answer suggests. Instead of doing `redirectTo: 'login'` make a loading component and replace with `redirectTo: 'loading'`

Comment: Glad to hear it. Happy coding!